# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `latest' for #<Class:0x007f8b5d07e5c8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, indexing, undefined, actionview

I've got this one error which i cannot work out, i understand that 'get :index' isn't linking up for some reason.

```
StoreControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method latest' for #<Class:0x007f8b5d07e5c8> app/views/store/index.html.erb:7:in _app_views_store_index_html_erb___4260644534451553693_70118269675460'
    test/controllers/store_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StoreControllerTest>
```

Here is the code for store_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class StoreControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select '#columns #side a', minimum: 4
    assert_select '#main .entry', 3
    assert_select 'h3', 'Programming Ruby 1.9'
    assert_select '.price', /\$[,\d]+\.\d\d/
  end

end
```

And here is the code for index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id='notice'> <%= notice %> </p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
<% cache ['entry', product] do %>
<div class='entry'>
<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class='price_line'>
<span class='price'><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
  </div>
 </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your `Product` model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `latest` method defined for `Product` class. You probably meant:

```
Product.last
```

Comment: @BradleyArnott was my answer helpful?

Comment: Typo in the book (Agile Web Dev with Rails 4)? Page 105.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I just ran into this. You should have the following method in app/models/product.rb

```
def self.latest
  Product.order(:updated_at).last
end
```

This is where it's referencing 'latest' from (page 104 in Agile Web Development with Rails 4)

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your self.latest method is placed within the Product class. This was an error in my case, I placed the method outside the class and it raised an error.